# In Florida, can a 24 year old have relationship with a 17 year old if their relationship started a year earlier?

Tags: criminal-law, marriage, consent, rape

In Florida, the age of consent is 18, but there is an exception that allows for people up to the age of 23 to have a relationship with someone 16 years and older.

> (1) A person 24 years of age or older who engages in sexual activity
>   with a person 16 or 17 years of age commits a felony of the second
>   degree, punishable as provided in s. 775.082, s. 775.083, or s.
>   775.084. As used in this section, “sexual activity” means oral, anal, or vaginal penetration by, or union with, the sexual organ of another;
>   however, sexual activity does not include an act done for a bona fide
>   medical purpose. (2) The provisions of this section do not apply to a
>   person 16 or 17 years of age who has had the disabilities of nonage
>   removed under chapter 743.

[See the law here](http://archive.flsenate.gov/statutes/index.cfm?mode=View%20Statutes&SubMenu=1&App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=794.05&URL=0700-0799/0794/Sections/0794.05.html)

What happens if during such a legal relationship, one of the parties turns 24. For example, a 23 year old dating a 16 year old. When the 23 year old turns 24, do they suddenly by law have to break up an existing relationship?

If that is the case, this would be a very strange law.

Comment: It would not be the first very strange law.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just below the section you quoted it says:

> (3) The victim’s prior sexual conduct is not a relevant issue in a prosecution under this section.

There is no stated provision for the case you mention. I suspect that the law would apply. Whether the authorities would choose to prosecute in such a case is a very different question. There might be caselaw  of this subject. I wouldn't know. If this is more than hypothetical, i would urge consulting a lawyer with local knowledge of criminal practice.

Comment: That sounds like a fun 24th birthday. "_Thanks for the birthday wishes honey, but we have to go to a lawyer to see if we could continue our relationship that was legal yesterday_"